# Adler-32 output does not match expected values

Tags: .net, compression, zlib

In my .NET code, I need to add a 4-byte Adler-32 value as trailer to my zlib compressed data (RFC 1950). Here is my C# function:

```
    private static readonly uint Modulus = 65521;
    public static int Adler32(byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
        uint a = 1, b = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < length; ++counter) {
            a = (a + (data[offset + counter])) % Modulus;
            b = (b + a) % Modulus;
        }
        return unchecked((int)((b << 16) + a));
    }
```

And here's how I am getting my four bytes:

```
    byte[] data = { 227, 228, 225, 5, 0 }; // compressed data
    int adler32 = Adler32(data, 0, data.Length);

    byte b1 = (byte)((adler32 >> 24) & 0xFF);
    byte b2 = (byte)((adler32 >> 16) & 0xFF);
    byte b3 = (byte)((adler32 >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byte b4 = (byte)((adler32 >> 0) & 0xFF);
```

The problem is, from examining an actual zlib-compressed data, the expected bytes are supposed to be {0, 67, 0, 35} but the values I am getting are {10, 177, 2, 174}. What is it that I am doing wrong? Regards.

PS: For those interested, the actual input to zlib compression is {9, 12, 13}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the function was correct. It is just that the checksum must be run on the original uncompressed data and not on the result of compression. Basically, running Adler32() on {9, 12, 13} gave me the desired result. Regards.